# VSTS Callback uri for Android app

Tags: android, oauth, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to make an android app to get my VSO items.
I am following the documentation here for the OAuth flow https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth

The authorisation and authentication calls require a redirect_uri to be passed in the POST requests. What would be that value for an Android app?

The URL must be secured as per VSTS guidelenes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0 article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth#qa):

> Q: Can I use OAuth with my phone app? A: No. Right now, Visual Studio
>   Team Services only support the web server flow, so there's no
>   supported way to implement OAuth for Visual Studio Team Services from
>   an app like a phone app, since there's no way to securely store the
>   app secret.

The workaround is that you can build a web app, then send the request to that web app from your Android app to retrieve necessary data.

Update:

If you can use Personal Access Token or Alternate authentication credentials, you can use it on your android app directly. (Can't access account and profile information)

Comment: Agreed.
In case we set up the Web App. How will the user authorize the app?

Comment: @ShaswatRungta You may consider Personal Access Token. Regarding authorize app, users need to authorize through web app manually and you can store access token and refresh token in database and link this record to the user of your android app. The refresh token will be expired after one year.

Comment: @ShaswatRungta If you can use Personal Access Token or Alternate authentication credentials, you can use it on your android app directly. (Can't access account and profile information)

Comment: Since it is an Android app, copying the PAF token from the VSO website and putting it in the app is a bad experience. I want the auth flow to be natural to the user.

Comment: @ShaswatRungta Since OAuth isn't be supported for phone app, it's just a workaround, the PAT can be expired in a year. Build a web app for Oauth and link to the user of phone app (could be in a database) is better.